# Python, delimiter for csv ';'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

It is a simple task to change two columns in .csv file. I use this code:

```
inn = open('tk.csv', 'w')

import csv

with open('input_2.csv') as File:
     reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')


    for row in reader:
        a = row[0]
        b = row[1]
        a, b = b, a
        print(a,b, file=inn)
```

And it gives me the mane and value in the same column, separated by a blank space. I know, that in answer there should be delimiter ";" as in the input .csv to separate the name and value on 2 different columns. What should I do?

Comment: The `delimiter` parameter is only used for your csv.reader. If you want to write CSV out as well, use [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write the file - and not `print`.

Comment: Use `print(f"{a};{b}", file=inn)` instead of `print(a,b, file=inn)`

Comment: Are you asking why the `delimiter` is not applied when *writing* the "csv"? Are you aware that you have only created a ``csv.reader``, not a ``csv.writer``?

Answer (score 0):

```
print("%s,%s"%(a, b), file=inn)
# delimiter is comma above you can change it to whatever you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `;` as a delimiter in your output, you should write one. The delimiter you use is only relevant for the input.

You can

- either use `print("%s;%s" % (a, b), file=inn)` for outputting the delimiter,
- or you can instruct `print()` to produce the correct delimiter (`print(a, b, sep=';', file=inn)`),
- or you can use [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer), which is the recommended way.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is more simple to use!

Answer (score 0):

You should use csv.writer for writing to csv like that:

```
import csv

with open('tk.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=';')
    with open('input_2.csv') as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            a = row[0]
            b = row[1]
            a, b = b, a
            writer.writerow([a, b])
```